# What's wrong with this shell script syntax?

Tags: linux, apache, shell, syntax

I'm trying to run the Apache startup script, `/etc/init.d/httpd`. Environment variable definitions like this one give an error:

```
CONF_FILE=$(APACHE_HOME)/conf/httpd.conf
```

It says `"/etc/init.d/httpd: line 15: APACHE_HOME: command not found"`

So, I replaced the parentheses with curly brackets, and the script worked swimmingly. What gives? I'm really just asking this question because I want to understand why it's wrong, not how to fix it. The shebang is there, and it's unmodified from the original shell script, so why's it misinterpreting things?

Comment: Why brackets? Leave them

Comment: `$(foo)` tries to run `foo` as a command, and substitutes that command's output. APACHE_HOME is not a command.

Comment: `$()` is command interpolation, `${}` is variable substitution

Comment: Why is Apache's httpd file wrong, though?

Comment: `$(VAR)` is a variable expansion in a Makefile.  Perhaps the file you are looking at is intended to be parsed by something other than a shell.

Comment: @slothario That is really a surprising question to me as we;;. How come the Apache config file have this issue? Haven't they tested it for all shells? Anyone, please comment on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In unix systems:

```
$SOMETHING /* variable */
$(SOMETHINGELSE) /* command */
${FOO} */ variable substitution */
```

Comment: Yes, I see that now, but why is httpd wrong? It was written by Apache!

Answer (score 1):

`$(something)` tells the shell to execute command `something` and substitute the command's output.<sup>1</sup>

You want to substitute a *variable's* output, so you just need a `$` in front of the variable, like so: `CONF_FILE=$APACHE_HOME/conf/httpd.conf`

Alternatively, you could use `CONF_FILE=${APACHE_HOME}/conf/httpd.conf` (note the curly braces instead of parenthesis), but it's not really necessary for your situation.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is useful when you want to assign a *command's* output to a variable.  For example:

```
MY_VAR="$(egrep 'someline' somefile.txt)"
```

Comment: In an assignment like that the quotes aren't necessary around a variable.

Answer (score 1):

`$(...)` executes its contents in a subshell, it doesn't get the value of a variable. You can use just plain `$APACHE_HOME` or `${APACHE_HOME}`, which it sounds like you switched to.